# win32gui findwindow doesn't work win7

Tags: python-2.7, win32gui

I use the code below to activate the command promt:

```
hwn = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Prompt dei comandi - python demo.py")
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwn)
```

Prompt dei comandi is the italian word of command promt :) and demo.py is the name of the python file.
It works perfectly with window xp but when i try the same code with win7 it doesn't work anymore.
I also check the list of the visible windows with this code:

```
import win32gui
def window_enum_handler(hwnd, resultList):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd) and win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) != '':
        resultList.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)))

def get_app_list(handles=[]):
    mlst=[]
    win32gui.EnumWindows(window_enum_handler, handles)
    for handle in handles:
        mlst.append(handle)
    return mlst


appwindows = get_app_list()
return appwindows
for i in appwindows:
   print i
```

In that list i can see: Prompt dei comandi - python demo.py
What does it change from win xp to win7??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things that could be. But I think it's about ANSI and UNICODE. Try using:

```
hwn = win32gui.FindWindow(None, u"Prompt dei comandi - python demo.py")
```

Or maybe using ctypes:

```
from ctypes import windll

FindWindowW = windll.user32.FindWindowW
FindWindowA = windll.user32.FindWindowA

print FindWindowW(0, u"Prompt dei comandi - python demo.py")
print FindWindowA(0, "Prompt dei comandi - python demo.py")
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the only different was just on one space!
i will explain my self:
this works for win xp:

```
hwn = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Prompt dei comandi - python demo.py")
```

this works for win7:

```
hwn = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Prompt dei comandi - python  demo.py")
```

it sounds crazy but it does.